# Ceiling fan light turns off when i pull the fan cord to adjust fan speeds

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

Intermittent issue. Ceiling fan lights turn off when I pull the fan cord to adjust speeds. When this happens the only way to turn the Ceiling fan lights back on is to flick the wall switch off and then back on for lights to come back on. Then pull fan cord again to desired speed or off. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are the bulbs in the fan incandescent, CFL, or LED?

Comment: You will need to disassemble the fan to look at the connections to the lights. There may be a connector or wire that is loose.